# Using electromagnets to hover a craft independently of the surface below it

Tags: electromagnetism

Why isn't this possible? I've seen the ducted fans, it works (even if it is very rough). I've also seen the magnetic boards that hover above a special magnetic-reactive surface. But that isn't true hovering in the sense of usability as you cannot leave that surface and you cannot surely expect a proper surface to be everywhere so your hoverboard is quite ineffective as the ATV that we've always wanted in a device like this.

So my question is this: why can't a device with a strong powerplant charge electromagnets that are facing eachother to repel, hover? I have had this idea since I was a child but no one really can tell me why or why it won't work.

I do not understand physics that well and I am sure there is an obvious answer. It makes no sense to me why it won't work.

Comment: For more on [hoverboards](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=hendo+hoverboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you're trying to fly, and you get a brilliant idea, which is to stoop down and just pick yourself up by your feet! You grab a shoelace in each hand and lift up on it, but you don't start flying like you expect: you are pulling up on your feet, so they should lift up; but your feet are also pulling down on your arms, which are attached to your body which is attached legs which are attached to your feet... So all you end up doing is straining your muscles to compress yourself together and maybe snap a shoelace.

The same sort of thing happens if you have two electromagnetics repelling each other while both are attached to the same vehicle frame: the lower magnet pushes up on the upper magnet, yes, but the upper magnet also pushes down on the lower magnet... Which pulls down on the frame that the upper magnet is attached to. So you end up putting a lot of energy into tensing the frame without hovering anywhere.

The only option for a hoverboard is to react against something that is not attached to it: a special surface for Hendo hoverboards, the atmosphere for ducted fans, etc... Otherwise the hoverboard is as useless as trying to pick yourself up by your feet. The equal and opposite forces keep you from accelerating upward independently.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. It makes sense and puts it all into perspective. So it goes with one of the laws of physics. To gain thrust, you have to give something away. And you're not really giving it away if you're keeping it on you. lol

Answer (score 0):

And that is because concrete, asphalt, grass, etc. are not magnetic.

The one possibility that I can think of is to use high-voltage (low-current, if possible) ion thrusters, such as in ionocraft. The characters in children's TV shows that seem to hover above the ground may use high-voltage ion thrusters as well. I can tell you that the technology may one day get there to use the Earth's magnetic field to hover a heavy aircraft, for example, but right now we're just not there yet.

Comment: I understand fully and I cited that in my post. My question is that why does pointing two magnets right at eachother with different power levels for each one, not work? Why can't we make a hovercraft with these two magnets repelling eachother alone?

Comment: The magnetic forces would either push the object away from the magnet or be insufficient to counteract the gravitational attraction if the magnetism is too weak. In your case, say you were trying to magnetically levitate on grass or soil or concrete. Those things have virtually NO magnetism!